# Change zap log level dynamically for some of the code

Tags: go, logging

I'm used to work with java and log4j, in which I could dynamically change the log level for a single class without any additional (coding) effort.

Now, when I work with golang ([zap](https://godoc.org/go.uber.org/zap) for logging) – I seek the same functionality, but cannot find it.

Is there an easy way to change log level dynamically for a file or a package or a part of the code?

Answer (score 3):

[zap](https://godoc.org/go.uber.org/zap) supports `log.Logger` wrapping via constructors like [NewStdLog](https://godoc.org/go.uber.org/zap#NewStdLog), so if you want to keep using `zap` then the following technique will work:

---

If you don't want to use a third-party loggers, the following technique is quite simple, using go's standard library `log.Logger`:

Define some default app loggers:

```
var (
    pkgname = "mypkgname"
    Info  = log.New(os.Stdout, "[INFO:"+pkgname+"] ", log.LstdFlags)
    Debug = log.New(ioutil.Discard, "[DBUG:"+pkgname+"] ", log.LstdFlags|log.Lshortfile)
    Trace = log.New(ioutil.Discard, "[TRCE:"+pkgname+"] ", log.LstdFlags|log.Lmicroseconds|log.Lshortfile)
)
```

so by default `Info` will write to `Stdout` - but `Debug` & `Trace` will go be "off" by default.

One can then, *safely* (i.e. goroutine-safe) turn these `log.Loggers` on/off either at start time:

```
func init() {
    if v, ok := os.LookupEnv("DEBUG"); ok && v != "" {
        Info.Println("ENV VAR 'DEBUG' set: enabling debug-level logging")
        Debug.SetOutput(os.Stderr)
    }
}
```

or during runtime:

```
func httpServiceHandler(r *req) {
    if r.TraceingOn {
        Trace.SetOutput(os.Stderr)
    } else {
        Trace.SetOutput(ioutil.Discard)
    }
}
```

Logging at pkg level is just like any other `log` method:

```
Debug.Printf("http request: %+v", r)
```

And if there's an expensive log event that you don't want to generate - if say the logger is set to `discard` - you can safely check the state of the logger like so:

```
if Trace.Writer() != ioutil.Discard {
    // do expensive logging here

    // e.g. bs, _ = ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body);  Trace.Println("RESP: RAW-http response:", string(bs))
}
```